# To find Area bounded by curve and my attempt

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I amnot getting correct answer , i am getting 7/2 but textbook states 3/2 .Can someone throw light on my path ? THANKS

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Care to comment down voter?

Comment: (not a downvoter!) Our function is $1$ when $1\le x+y\lt 2$ and $0$ when $0\le x+y\lt 0$. Easiest is to find the area of the big triangle, subtract the area of the small triangle. We get $2-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas OH Yes i didn't noticed it , it becomes easiest this way .Thanks

Comment: You are welcome. The geometry is very helpful in solving this kind of problem, either directly as in my comment, or indirectly in setting up the integral. When I am solving such a problem, I still always draw a picture. Without a picture I *might* get things right, but I would not *know* that I am right. (You drew a picture, good step. But then an accident happened.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your separation of integrals should go
$$\int_1^2 \int_0^{y-2} dx dy +\int_0^1 \int_{y-1}^{y-2} dx dy.$$

Comment: Oh yes my mistake .thanks